# JQuery to change the color of the text for the entire row in a Sharepoint List

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint-online

I am trying to change a script to change the color of the text for an entire row based on a value.

I have changed the script to use `parent()`, but it does not change the text color. It works with other css such as "background-color" or "text-decoration", but not "color".

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script><script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $Status = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('Rush')").filter(function() {return 
  $(this).text() == "Rush";});
  $Status.css({"color": "red"});
  $Status = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('Expedite')");
  $Status.css({"color": "orange"});
});
</script>
```

The code above will only change the value of the cell. I would like to change the entire row to the color.

Comment: Can you post the code of the row?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.parent()` to select the parent row of the cell you are checking the text. I know you said you used it and it didn't work, but I got it working in the example below.

You also are using the selector `:contains` to filter by text, then are using `.filter` to filter it again which is uneeded and might be breaking things. so I removed the `.filter`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $Rush = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('Rush')");
  $Rush.parent().css({
    "color": "red"
  });

  var $Expedite = $("td.ms-vb2:contains('Expedite')");
  $Expedite.parent().css({
    "color": "orange"
  });
});
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<table>
<tr><td class="ms-vb2">Rush</td><td>More</td><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ms-vb2">Expedite</td><td>More</td><td>Data</td></tr>
<tr><td class="ms-vb2">Other</td><td>More</td><td>Data</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still will does not work. For some reason the "color" will not change the parent(), only the child(). Removing the .filter still has the same results. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to use [CSR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) for such requirement(classic view).

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
      //logic to check field value
      var isApproved = rows[i]["_ModerationStatus"] == "Approved";
      if (isApproved)
      {
        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#ada";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[Another thread for your reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)

Comment: Again, unfortunately this is for background color which is not the issue. I am looking to change the color of the text of the entire row in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code as suggested above. It works better because the page coloring will still work with filters after the page is re-rendered. Unfortunately I still cannot change the color of the text. Only the background color. I have searched the web and cannot understand why .color does not work. This is for a Modern Sharepoint Library Web Part using the Content Web Part to add the code.

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
      //logic to check field value
      var isStatus = rows[i]["Rush_x0020_Job_x003f_"] == "Rush";
      if (isStatus)
      {
        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
  tr.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
      }
   var isStatus = rows[i]["Rush_x0020_Job_x003f_"] == "Expedited";
      if (isStatus)
      {
        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "Orange";
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to change the color of the text in my Status Cell rather than the whole row and this worked. I am posting this change for anyone who might be attempting something similar...

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender:
  function ColourDv(ctx)
  {
    var header = document.querySelector("[name=Rush_x0020_Job_x003f_]").parentNode;
    var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < ctx.ListData.Row.length; i++)
   {
        var listItem = ctx.ListData.Row[i];
        var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, listItem);
        var row = document.getElementById(iid);
        var dStatus = listItem.Rush_x0020_Job_x003f_;
        var cell = row.querySelector("td:nth-child(" + index + ")")

  if (dStatus == "Rush")
  {
       cell.style.color = "Red";
     cell.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  }

  if (dStatus == "Expedited")
  {
       cell.style.color = "Orange";
     cell.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  }

 }
  }
});
</script>
```